# How to turn on VS Code's semantic highlighing only for one language?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to have semantic highlighting only for Rust and not other languages, but this seems not to be possible in practice.

After defining the "semanticTokenColors" it turns on semantic highlighting for all languages, not only for Rust. I've made an issue report on VS Code's repo but so far no response.

I've tried putting "semanticTokenColors" on the themecolor.json and in the settings.json.

Here are my current settings:

```
    "editor.semanticHighlighting.enabled": false,
    "[rust]": {
        "editor.semanticHighlighting.enabled": true
    },
    "editor.semanticTokenColorCustomizations": {
        "[JetBrains Darcula Theme]": {
            "rules": {
                "*.attribute": {
                    "foreground": "#BBB529"
                },
                "lifetime": {
                    "foreground": "#20999D"
                },
                "typeParameter": {
                    "foreground": "#20999D"
                },
                "*.mutable": {
                    "foreground": "#BCA5C4",
                    "underline": true
                },
                "macro": {
                    "foreground": "#4EADE5"
                },
                "macroBang": {
                    "foreground": "#4EADE5"
                },
                "enumMember": {
                    "foreground": "#9876AA"
                },
                "*.constant": {
                    "foreground": "#9876AA"
                },
                "string": {
                    "foreground": "#6A8759"
                },
                "unresolvedReference": {
                    "foreground": "#9876AA"
                },
                "operator": {
                    "foreground": "#abb2bf"
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: any difference if you instead use `"editor.semanticHighlighting.enabled": "configuredByTheme"` in the `"[rust]"` block?

Comment: @user no difference, my theme has semantic highlighting off by default.

Answer (score 1):

- disable it in User/Global setting
- create a `rust` language setting in `settings.json` and enable it

```json
  "editor.semanticHighlighting.enabled": false,
  "[rust]": {
    "editor.semanticHighlighting.enabled": true
  }
```

Comment: That's what I have right now in the `settings.json`, still doesn't work and I'll get semantic Highlighting in C too, for example.

Comment: @bernardoamorim Why don't you show the relevant parts of `settings.json` in the question

Comment: Edited the post to have those @rioV8

Answer (score 0):

While the original issue still prevails, I found out how to specify the language in semanticTokenColors: "variable.readonly:java is called a selector and has the form (|tokenType)(.tokenModifier)(:tokenLanguage)?.", according to [the official vs code guide](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/semantic-highlight-guide).

Comment: @user Ence why the issue, the original one, still prevails, but I found how to "fix" my problem in another way and some people might find it useful. I asked my question as best as I could. This is another way to get language specific semantic highlighting.